# Mongoose aggregate in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I aggregate in monggose in the following syntax

I want to group the results by 'aptType' and 'aptStatus' and get the count for each after grouping.

```
router.route('/api/apartments/getstats')             
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Apartment.find({$group:{_id:{'aptType':'$aptType','aptStatus':'$aptStatus'},count:{$sum:1}}},function(err, apartments) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(apartments);
         });
   });
```

below is the mongoose Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ApartmentSchema = new Schema({
    BusinessUnit:String,
    aptID: String,
    aptType: String,    
    aptStatus: String,
 });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Apartment', ApartmentSchema);
```

Documents sample as follows

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5754cec6dcba0f2aab5c0bca"
    },
    "aptID": "402",
    "aptType": "1BHK",
    "aptStatus": "Available",
    "BusinessUnit": "Business Unit One", 
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5754cec6dcba0f2aab5c0bca"
    },
    "aptID": "402",
    "aptType": "1BHK",
    "aptStatus": "Not-Available",
    "BusinessUnit": "Business Unit One", 
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5754cec6dcba0f2aab5c0bca"
    },
    "aptID": "402",
    "aptType": "2BHK",
    "aptStatus": "Not-Available",
    "BusinessUnit": "Business Unit One", 
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5754cec6dcba0f2aab5c0bca"
    },
    "aptID": "402",
    "aptType": "2BHK",
    "aptStatus": "Available",
    "BusinessUnit": "Business Unit One", 
}
```

Comment: Can you add some sample document and mongoose schema here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually aggregation query:

```
{$group:{_id:{'aptType':'$aptType','aptStatus':'$aptStatus'},count:{$sum:1}}}
```

is correct, if you want to get next result (grouped by both: aptType and aptStatus):

```
[ { _id: { aptType: '2BHK', aptStatus: 'Available' }, count: 1 },
  { _id: { aptType: '1BHK', aptStatus: 'Available' }, count: 1 },
  { _id: { aptType: '2BHK', aptStatus: 'Not-Available' }, count: 1 },
  { _id: { aptType: '1BHK', aptStatus: 'Not-Available' }, count: 1 } ]
```

The issue is that you need to use `Apartment.aggregate` instead of `Apartment.find`

**UPDATE**

Here is the full working example:

```
let express = require('express');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let app = express();
let router = express.Router();

const MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost/test';
const PORT = 8888;

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI);
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log(`Connected to ${MONGO_URI}`);
});

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let ApartmentSchema = new Schema({
    BusinessUnit: String,
    aptID: String,
    aptType: String,
    aptStatus: String
});

let Apartment = mongoose.model('Apartment', ApartmentSchema);

router.route('/api/apartments/getstats')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Apartment.aggregate({$group:{_id:{'aptType':'$aptType','aptStatus':'$aptStatus'},count:{$sum:1}}},function(err,  apartments) {
            if (err) res.send(err);
            res.json(apartments);
        });
    });

app.use(router);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Good practice is to split this code into server, dbmodel and router